# Processing: increasing performance?

Tags: performance, processing, settings, system

This question is specifically related to the program Processing.

Does anyone know if Processing is by default limited to CPU/RAM usage defaults? I'm integrating it into a facility at my university on a ridiculously powerful system (24 cores, 36GB in graphics power and a stupid amount of RAM). Yet, some sketches run at a poor frame rate (10-20 per second), which isn't much better than my MacBook Pro, so I feel there's something wrong. I've tried multiple renderers as well. For example, the flocking example that comes with Processing couldn't handle more than a few hundred objects (which wasn't much more than any other computer could), or with 3D scenes only a few hundred boxes causes a very laggy navigating experience. OPEN GL rendering didn't seem to make a big difference.

Does anyone know what this might be? It's been hard searching for "processing performance" in relation to the actual program "Processing". Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please be more specific than saying you're expecting your sketches to run better? What exactly does better mean?

Keep in mind that Processing defaults to 60 frames per second, which is independent of the hardware you're running it on. You can adjust this by calling the `frameRate()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

Also note that Processing uses a single thread to do all of its rendering and event callbacks. So throwing more CPU cores at it won't really do much, unless you specifically offload some of your work to another thread. And with a graphics-driven framework like Processing, that can be more work than it's worth.

Can you please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (just enough code so we can copy and paste it to run ourselves, **not** your full project) that shows exactly what you're trying to do? Don't forget to include exactly what you expect to happen compared to what actually happens.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. It's just a frame rate issue. I haven't tried explicitly calling frameRate(60) as I thought that was defaulted. I don't have access to the sketches I was running at the time right now, but essentially the main drag on them was either having too many objects rendered (flocking example in Processing couldn't handle too many objects) or navigating a 3D scene in a large canvas. I'd like to think I was asking too much of the machine but the specs are incredible. I've added this info to my original post, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @themessup I've added another paragraph to my answer, specifically talking about the fact that Processing uses a single thread for its rendering, so throwing more CPU cores at it won't drastically change its performance.

Comment: I think that's the answer I needed. Makes sense. thanks!

Comment: @themessup No problem. I should also note that Processing uses a single rendering thread on purpose: having multiple threads rendering at the same time introduces a ton of problems that you don't want to have to deal with. You want your draw commands to execute in a predictable order, so using a single thread is the way to go. But if you can offload some of the processing to other threads, then you can increase your performance that way.